# Static IPs for Asus router VPN clients

Tags: openvpn, static-ip, asus

I have asus router RT-AC58U (fw 3.0.0.4.382_51899) and have successfully set up OpenVPN.
Here are my custom settings:
[OpenVPN custom settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JJay.png)

these setting automatically generate file

> config.ovpn

```
# Automatically generated configuration

# Tunnel options
proto udp
multihome
port 1194
dev tun21
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
keepalive 15 60
daemon vpnserver1
verb 3
status-version 2
status status 10
comp-lzo adaptive
plugin /usr/lib/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so openvpn

# Server Mode
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
client-config-dir ccd
client-to-client
duplicate-cn
route 10.8.0.8 255.255.255.128
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 vpn_gateway 500"
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.1.1"

# Data Channel Encryption Options
auth SHA1

# TLS Mode Options
ca ca.crt
dh dh.pem
cert server.crt
key server.key

# Custom Configuration
```

I know it is possible to to create file in **ccd** directory with

```
ifconfig-push ip mask
```

but I cannot create them manually, everything is generated.
I can enable client specific options and add clients throught ui, which generates **ccd** directory with client files, but the generated content looks like this:

```
iroute 10.8.0.8 255.255.255.128
```

Is it possible to assign VPN clients static IP addresses?

I also have only one client.ovpn possible to export which has always the same **CN == client**

Comment: Can you generate an "iroute 10.8.0.9 10.8.0.10" ? This will generate a static on each side with a /30 netmask. (You can use 10.8.0.8 as that is not a valid IP when dealing ng with /30's)

Comment: Yes, I generated also "iroute 10.8.0.9 10.8.0.10" but nothing changed, still got some IP like 10.8.0.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to make it work by applying following steps:

1. You need to activate ssh access to your router (+ setup username and password)
2. Login to your router `ssh username@routerIp`
3. There is a writable directory `/jffs`. Create some config structure under it e.g. `/jffs/configs/openvpn/ccd` (use `mkdir`)
4. In `ccd` dir create file with same name as your vpn client username (e.g. `touch nuc`)
5. Write config for your client in this file (`vi nuc`)
6. Write your client's config there using format `ifconfig-push staticIP mask` (e.g. `ifconfig-push 10.0.8.10 255.255.255.0`) and save
7. Leave secure shell (`exit`)
8. Log into your router's ui, go to OpenVpn setup menu and fill the path to your client config into `"Custom Configuration"` field: `client-config-dir /jffs/configs/openvpn/ccd` Also don't forget to switch `Username / Password Auth. Only` to `"Yes"` (otherwise client config files should be named by client's CN)
9. Save router config clicking on `Apply` button

Now you can connect with vpn client and you will get the set up IP (mine was 10.0.8.10)