# Asus OpenVPN Server Static IP

Tags: openvpn, router, static-ip, asus

I follow [Static IPs for Asus router VPN clients](https://serverfault.com/questions/989510/static-ips-for-asus-router-vpn-clients).

Still unable to let the client get static ip

My method of executing `openvpn` is `sudo openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/client/client.ovpn`

1. SSH connect to Asus Router
2. Go to the `jffs` folder,

   ```
   mkdir configs
   cd configs
   mkdir openvpn
   cd openvpn
   mkdir ccd
   cd ccd
   touch nuc
   vi nuc
   ifconfig-push 10.8.0.22 255.255.255.0
   ```
3. Exit SSH.
4. Asus Router Web Settings -> `http://192.168.0.1/` -> VPN -> OpenVpn -> Custom Configuration -> `client-config-dir /jffs/configs/openvpn /ccd`
5. Username / Password Auth. Only to "Yes"
6. Allowed Clients

   - Common Name(CN) => `tester` (the account set by my OpenVPN)
   - Subnet => `10.8.0.0`
   - Mask => `255.255.255.0`
   - Push => `No`

What other settings does the Server have to do? Or is there anything to be added to the key?

I just need to follow the steps in the answer

I didn’t make any changes to the rest

Are there other places to set?

Answer (score 2):

For me, it looks like you gave the client config file (`nuc`) the wrong name. OpenVPN works this way, that each of the possibly very many clients can have its own config - and the config file for one specific client is distinguished by the Common Name of the Client, as the common name is unique.

If your client's common name is `tester` as you write, you have to rename the client config file inside the `ccd` directory to `tester`, and it should work...

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem lies with the `nuc` `tester`, and it works now!